# Get the number of "tap" on a locked smartwatch screen

Tags: java, android, kotlin, moto-360

I'm doing a school project as a team, but none of us have never developed or even worn smartwatches.

We want to **get the number of "tap" on a smartwatch's locked screen** but we don't find out if that's possible.

1. Do you know a way to get the number of "tap" on a locked smartwatch screen?
2. If this is not possible, can we display a constant notification and retrieve the number of "tap" on this notification?

I'm using a Moto 360 with Android 6.0.1 and Android Wear 1.4.0.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't even mention which version of Android compatible smartwatch you are targeting: older Android Wear, current Google Wear OS, Samsung Tizen, or you are using a completely 'regular' Android OS based watch. I.e. doing a project that you have no familiarity with requires a lot of research.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I now have more information : I have a Moto 360 with Android 6.0.1 and Android Wear 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise everyone on the team get a chance to the use watch just to understand the user experience. Watches are very battery limited devices and will always try to go into low power mode as often as possible.

> Do you know a way to get the number of "tap" on a locked smartwatch screen?

Tapping normally wakes up watch, either from full screen off or lower power ambient mode. If you want to capture taps/button press you can create a watch app which when active will receive taps/button presses. I'm not quite sure if watch face can capture taps, and if it did it my guess would be after the watch face is fully on, but that would be another place to look.

> If this is not possible, can we display a constant notification and retrieve the number of "tap" on this notification?

Custom watch face can allow display of custom content. Alternatively as a watch app you can show what you want.

**Additional Comments**

The Moto 360 came out in 2014 and was one of first Android Wear watches available. The latest code samples & codelabs from Google are for Wear OS 2.0. You can look back in the commit history for old versions of samples which may be more compatible with Android Wear 1.4

Also from this [Android Wear Notice May 2015](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-wear/Dm-_S6xxtS4) always on apps became possible so that might work for your project/use case.